# Pages being deleted when making a change

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, troubleshooting

I have been working in SharePoint for a few months editing in both SharePoint itself and using SharePoint Designer 2010. Today Sharepoint would no longer allow me to edit my website and was deleting whole pages when making 1 change.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it was deleting the page and not just your changes on that page? Often unsafe changes can be automatically removed when you save your changes. Additionally, some areas in SharePoint Designer can only be edited in Advanced Mode (available in the ribbon). Before using Advanced Mode I strongly recommend reading more about it, [here's](http://erikswenson.blogspot.com.au/2010/02/sharepoint-designer-2010-edit-in.html) a good starting point.

If you've checked these things and you're sure that the pages are actually deleting themselves then you should urgently chat with whoever's responsibility it is to look after the SharePoint Servers. If that's you, then you need to do some further diagnosing of the issue. [This link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210652.aspx) will help teach you how to read the SharePoint Logs as well as further diagnose potential issues.

Good luck, and let me know if I can be of any further help!